# DELPHI - How to use opendialog1 for choosing a folder?

Tags: delphi, directory, delphi-2010, opendialog

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Delphi: Selecting a directory with TOpenDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7422689/delphi-selecting-a-directory-with-topendialog)

I need to open a specific folder on my project. When I use opendialog1, I can only open a file. How about opening a folder ?

[image: wanted - open folder dialog in Delphi]

PS : I use Delphi 2010

Comment: Ken's answer (the only one so far) is great, but this seems like a dup of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7422689/delphi-selecting-a-directory-with-topendialog

Comment: In the fact, you can use the `TOpenDialog` descendant - `TSaveDialog` (yeah, thats quite quick and dirty)

Comment: Voted to close, but I'll be missing [`teran's answer`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9529154/960757) there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You also can use `TBrowseForFolder` action class (`stdActns.pas`):

```
var
  dir: string;
begin
  with TBrowseForFolder.Create(nil) do try
    RootDir  := 'C:\';
    if Execute then
      dir := Folder;
  finally
    Free;
  end;
end;
```

or use WinApi function - `SHBrowseForFolder` directly (second `SelectDirectory` overload uses it, instead of first overload, which creates own delphi-window with all controls at runtime):

```
var
  dir : PChar;
  bfi : TBrowseInfo;
  pidl : PItemIDList;
begin
  ZeroMemory(@bfi, sizeof(bfi));
  pidl := SHBrowseForFolder(bfi);
  if pidl <> nil then try
    GetMem(dir, MAX_PATH + 1);
    try
      if SHGetPathFromIDList(pidl, dir) then begin
        // use dir
      end;
    finally
      FreeMem(dir);
    end;
  finally
    CoTaskMemFree(pidl);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: lines 13,14 could be replaced with `CoTaskMemFree`

Answer (score 19):

On Vista and up you can show a more modern looking dialog using `TFileOpenDialog`.

```
var
  OpenDialog: TFileOpenDialog;
  SelectedFolder: string;
.....
OpenDialog := TFileOpenDialog.Create(MainForm);
try
  OpenDialog.Options := OpenDialog.Options + [fdoPickFolders];
  if not OpenDialog.Execute then
    Abort;
  SelectedFolder := OpenDialog.FileName;
finally
  OpenDialog.Free;
end;
```

which looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 11):

You're looking for `SelectDirectory` in the `FileCtrl` unit. It has two overloaded versions:

```
function SelectDirectory(var Directory: string; 
   Options: TSelectDirOpts; HelpCtx: Longint): Boolean;
function SelectDirectory(const Caption: string; const Root: WideString; 
var Directory: string; Options: TSelectDirExtOpts; Parent: TWinControl): Boolean;
```

The one you want to use depends on the version of Delphi you're using, and the specific appearance and functionality you're looking for; I( usually find the second version works perfectly for modern versions of Delphi and Windows, and users seem happy with the "normally expected appearance and functionality".

Comment: +1 Ken, btw the unit name is `FileCtrl`.

Comment: Both functions were moved out of the `FileCtrl` unit a long time ago.

Comment: Rodrigo, thanks for the correction. Fixed. @Remy, the [docs for XE2](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/FileCtrl.SelectDirectory) say you're wrong. If they were moved "a long time ago" the docs should mention that fact.

Comment: Nevermind.  Other `FileCtrl` functions were indeed moved to `SysUtils` a long time ago and their `FileCtrl` references were deprecated. I thought `SelectDirectory()` was amongst them, but I just checked and that is not the case afterall.