# Is it possible to make a filename non-editable using the Edit Box of the SaveDialog of Delphi7?

Tags: delphi

According to our requirements, we just want to enable the user to select a place to save a file and restrict the editing of its name.

Is it possible to that with inbuilt SaveDialog component of Delphi (7)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, but that isn't what you *really* want to do. What you want to do is not to select a *file name*, but to select a *folder*, and that is a different problem.

Using `FileCtrl`,

```
var
  dir: string;
begin
  if SelectDirectory('Select Directory','', dir, [sdNewUI, sdNewFolder]) then
    ShowMessage(dir);
```

On Vista+ you can also use the [directory selection mode of the file dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7422764/282848).

Comment: I think you're right about the real goal here, but if it is possible to do exactly what the OP asked, I would be interested to know the answer.

Comment: @ThijsvanDien: I think you only have to send a [`EM_SETREADONLY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761655(v=vs.85).aspx) message to the EDIT control.

Comment: That would keep the user from typing in a different name, but clicking an existing file would also cause the content to change.

Comment: @ThijsvanDien: True. Anyhow, that only emphasises my main point: This isn't what the OP *really* wants to do.

Comment: +1 It's actually not possible to do what @Learner wants. Yes you can make edit control read-only, if you can find it. But that in itself requires hacking and relies on implementation detail. Could change in future Windows. And it won't stop the filename being changed by clicking on the list view. So if I were you I would say "it cannot reasonably be done your way, the right way is to ask user to select folder".

Comment: In the dialog's `OnCanClose` event, you can check the entered filename and simply not allow the dialog to close if it does not match the intended value.

Comment: @Remy 
We can make use of onCanClose Event and we can make user to use only the name we want.
But there is a problem with this approach , What if we want to put a original file name that we want the user to enter.
Suppose i put the name in first occurrence and user edited it , We stopped the user .But after that is it possible to show the name in Edit box to user which we want him to use ?

Comment: procedure TForm1.SaveDialog1CanClose(Sender: TObject;
      var CanClose: Boolean);
    var
      location:String;
      name:String;
    begin

      name:=ExtractFileName(SaveDialog1.FileName);
      location:=ExtractFileDir(SaveDialog1.FileName);
     if name<>'Itstestfile.txt' then
     begin

      CanClose:=False;
      SaveDialog1.FileName:=location+'\Itstestfile.txt';   //is it possible to enter the original file name again in the edit box
      ShowMessage('can not change the file name');
     end else begin
      CanClose:=True;

     end;
    end; </pre>

Comment: @Learner: yes, it is possible, but not with the `FileName` property. You have to send a `CDM_SETCONTROLTEXT` message to the dialog instead: `SendMessage(GetParent(SaveDialog1.Handle), CDM_SETCONTROLTEXT, edt1, LPARAM(PChar(location+'\Itstestfile.txt')));` or `CommDlg_OpenSave_SetControlText(GetParent(SaveDialog1.Handle), edt1, PChar(location+'\Itstestfile.txt'));`