# Is it possible to select a folder/directory using TOpenDialog?

Tags: delphi-7

I've seen this question: [Selecting a directory with TOpenDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7422689/selecting-a-directory-with-topendialog)

Which technically is NOT answered (OP asked SPECIFICALLY about TOpenDialog - not TFileOpenDialog) but is applicable to later versions of Delphi.

I'm using Delphi 7 so TFileOpenDialog is not available.

So is it possible to use TOpenDialog to select a folder?

I know about SelectDirectory and have seen the other postings on that and I also know about BrowseFolder.

I am ONLY interested in answers that pertain to TOpenDialog.

I tried setting the Filename property to '*.' as someone suggested somewhere but that doesn't work.

Comment: TFileOpenDialog is buggy anyway. Only in Tokyo does it sort out library support. Use IFileDialog.

Comment: `TFileOpenDialog` is a wrapper for `IFileDialog`. In what way is it buggy?

Comment: @Remy Doesn't handle libraries for instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I've seen this question: [Selecting a directory with TOpenDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7422689/)
>
> Which technically is NOT answered

It is, well in one of the comments anyway:

"*TFileOpenDialog != TOpenDialog ... **TOpenDialog doesn't have such an option***"

That is the answer.

> I'm using Delphi 7 so TFileOpenDialog is not available.

No, it is not.  However, the underlying [`IFileDialog`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775966.aspx) and [`IFileOpenDialog`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775834.aspx) interfaces that it uses internally are standard Win32 COM interfaces (on Vista+ only), and as such they can be used in Delphi 7 just fine, as long as you have their declarations in your code.

> So is it possible to use TOpenDialog to select a folder?

The short answer is **NO**.

In Delphi 7, `TOpenDialog` is just a wrapper for the Win32 API [`GetOpenFileName()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646927.aspx) function, which can only select and return files, not folders.  You must use `SelectDirectory()` (which is just a wrapper for the Win32 API [`SHBrowseForFolder()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762115.aspx) function if you use the newer overload), or `IFileDialog`/`IFileOpenDialog` with the `FOS_PICKFOLDERS` option enabled.

In modern versions of Delphi, `TOpenDialog` does delegate to `IFileDialog`/`IFileOpenDialog` on Vista+ whenever possible (theming enabled, not using old VCL features that not expose by the newer dialog, etc), but it does not enable the `FOS_PICKFOLDERS` option.

Comment: I saw that comment but thought it was related to the specific TFileOpenDialog option mentioned (fdoPickFolders). That's pretty much the answer I expected but wanted to be sure. Thx for the additional info - I'll take a look at the interfaces.