# Where is the "Modern looking SelectDirectory function"?

Tags: delphi

This documentation page keep insisting that there is a "modern looking" SelectDirectory function.

https://www.embarcadero.com/products/rad-studio/windows-development?aldSet=en-GB

> New in 10 Seattle! Modern looking SelectDirectory function.

Where I can find that?

If I invoke FileCtrl.SelectDirectory a Win3.1-like dialog pop-ups:
[image]

Is this the new modern? Or am I missing "the other" SelectDirectory function?

Comment: (1) There are two overloads of `SelectDirectory`, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7422937/282848). One is Windows 3.1-styled and the other is the native Windows (95+) dialog. (2) In modern desktop applications, you should be using a standard open dialog to select directories, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7422764/282848). (3) These options both predate Seattle, so I don't know what they are talking about.

Comment: (But I have always considered the open dialog-based approach to be ... somewhat unnatural. For instance, if one directory is selected and I press Enter, then surely the file dialog will navigate to that directory? Or will the "Select Folder" button be invoked, as expected because it is the default button with a thick blue border, which will close the dialog and "return" this selected directory? Or will it return its parent, the current directory, instead?)

Comment: Couldn't they have named the function something else like SelectDirectoryEx? or modern? Anyway, as you said, still not modern...

Comment: No, that wouldn't have been confusing enough.

Comment: Since the comments there only mention it once: without _Delphi_ you get that dialog using [`SHBrowseForFolderW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shbrowseforfolderw) since _Windows 2000_. Done right you're able to add controls (i.e. a checkbox "recursively" or a button "create folder").

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since Delphi 10 Seattle there is a third overload of SelectDirectory with the following comment:

> Shows a select directory dialog using IFileDialog (recommended in
> Windows Vista or later).

The signature is:

```
function SelectDirectory(const StartDirectory: string; out Directories: TArray<string>; Options: TSelectDirFileDlgOpts = [];
  const Title: string = ''; const FolderNameLabel: string = ''; const OkButtonLabel: string = ''): Boolean; overload;
```

Comment: Ah, so it is effectively the same thing as the `TFileOpenDialog` approach, but with less boilerplate code.